# asp.net chart control and microsoft chart controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, charts

Can someone tell the difference between asp.net chart control and microsoft chart control.
Are they same or different?Also what is the best graphical tool for charting in IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

Refer:
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31858/ASP-NET-Charting-Controls
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235117/ASP-NET-4-0-Chart-Control

Also, other open source chart controls are available.
For Dashboards creation, paid Dundas Dashboard can be used.

Comment: is asp.net chart control and microsoft chart control are referring to the same?

Comment: Yes, and MS Chart control is a very enhanced version for charting. You can get sample codes for each chart type on msdn site and can easily build chart and graph dynamically also in simple steps. You can just define Series and Legends and bind your dataset to the Chart and thats it.